# removeClass setting display none

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, addclass, removeclass

html:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Hi</td>
        <td><a href="#">Click me</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

js:

```
$('td a').click(function (event) {
    var txt = $(this);
    event.preventDefault();
    txt.closest('td').addClass('info');
    txt.closest('td').fadeOut(500, function () {
        txt.closest('td').removeClass('info');
    });
    this.blur();
    txt.parent().attr('style', 'display: inherit;');
    return false;
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/iScripters/0dpLyv96/4/

When you click 'Click me', I want the class 'info' to be added to the parent (td), then removed using fadeout. Instead, it removes the entire .
Any solution or workaround for this?

Comment: fadeOut is supposed to make the opacity 0 right? so technically, it would go away..

Comment: I wanted to have only the class fadeout, not the entire element. Using setTimeOut now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here in the code, removeClass is not setting display:None, rather it is the functionality of fadeOut, that sets display to None. If you do not want it to be set to displayed to None, and to be removed after some duration of time, use function like setTimeOut. Link - http://www.sitepoint.com/jquery-settimeout-function-examples/

Comment: Thanks! This most closely does what I wanted it to do. Too bad it doesn't fade out now (the class, not the td :P) but at least it's disappearing!